# SQL SA Password change

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

So I have a batch file that is trying to change the SA password of a sql installation using mixed authentication:

```
:WINT
CLS
SET /P COMPUTERNAME=Enter the name of your Server: 
SET /P INSTANCE=Enter the name of your SQL instance: 
SET /P NEWPASS=Enter your new password: 
sqlcmd -S "%COMPUTERNAME%\%INSTANCE%" -Q "[master].[sys].[xp_instance_regwrite]  @rootkey = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'  ,@key = N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer'  ,@value_name = N'loginMode'  ,@type = N'REG_DWORD'  ,@value = 2;"
sqlcmd -S "%COMPUTERNAME%\%INSTANCE%" -Q "alter login sa with password='%NEWPASS%'"
sqlcmd -S "%COMPUTERNAME%\%INSTANCE%" -Q "alter login sa enable"
net stop MSSQL$%INSTANCE% && net start MSSQL$%INSTANCE% 
sqlcmd -b
PAUSE
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==1 GOTO END2
ELSE IF GOTO END1
```

My problem is that this batch file seems to be 2008 R2 specific as that is the only environment I am able to get it to work properly in. 
**So my question is this really; Does anyone know of a way to create a batch file that will enable mixed authentication and then change the SA password for any version of windows (server/enterprise/home/pro)?**

I need it to do this without the user knowing what their SA password is (assuming they are at least within the local admin group), because the purpose of this batch is to enable the user to change their SA password if they have forgotten it.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Executing scripts without knowing what they do is dangerous. The script is *not* specific to any version of Windows or SQL Server (at least since SQL Server 2005). It executes a couple of SQL commands then restarts the server. The first command though tries to change the authentication mode. The third, tries to enable `sa` - this could also complain if `sa` is already enabled. In fact, the *only* command needed to change the password is the second `sqlcmd` call. Why don't you use SSMS to change the password? Do you get a specific error?

Comment: PS. if you don't want users to know the SA password, why don't you use Windows Authentication only, and assign priviledges to users as needed?

Comment: According to the Best Business Practices (BBP) and the security Security Technical Implimentation Guide (STIG): The sa account must be renamed to something else and disabled to meet compliance. @Stan Shaw you are right on the money.

Answer (score 1):

I would stop what you're doing right now.  First off, end-users shouldn't have SA permissions.  If they DO need SA permissions, then what's the use in denying them access to the SA password?

That said, what you should do is use windows authentication and manage the permissions through SSMS.  If that's too complex, you can create SQL users with the permissions that users need - and then make the application use that account when logging into SQL (that's in the connection string).  Few ways to go about this, but I can't imagine a scenario where your end-users need SA permissions, can't have the SA password, and you need to periodically change the SA password from a batch file.  What the hell is going on here?!?